# How to import a PostgreSQL data file into Amazon redshift

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, import, command-line-interface, amazon-redshift

I am trying to import a PostgreSQL data file into Amazon redshift using my command line. I did import the schema file but can not import data file. It seems that data insertion in amazon redshift is a bit different.

I want to know all kinds of way of importing data file into redshift using command line.

**UPDATE**

My data file looks like :

```
COPY actor (actor_id, first_name, last_name, last_update) FROM stdin; 
0 Chad Murazik 2014-12-03 10:54:44
1 Nelle Sauer 2014-12-03 10:54:44
2 Damien Ritchie 2014-12-03 10:54:44
3 Casimer Wiza 2014-12-03 10:54:44
4 Dana Crist 2014-12-03 10:54:44
....
```

I typed the following command from CLI:

```
PGPASSWORD=**** psql -h testredshift.cudmvpnjzyyy.us-west-2.redshift.amazonaws.com -p 5439 -U abcd -d pagila -f /home/jamy/Desktop/pag_data.sql`
```

And then got error like :

> ERROR: LOAD source is not supported. (Hint: only S3 or DynamoDB or EMR based load is allowed

Comment: What do you mean by "data file"? Is that a file with SQL `INSERT` statements? CSV? Output from `pg_dump`?

Comment: output from pg_dump for example: 

COPY actor (actor_id, first_name, last_name, last_update) FROM stdin;
0 Chad Murazik 2014-12-03 10:54:44
1 Nelle Sauer 2014-12-03 10:54:44
2 Damien Ritchie 2014-12-03 10:54:44
3 Casimer Wiza 2014-12-03 10:54:44
4 Dana Crist 2014-12-03 10:54:44

Comment: "all kind of way[s]"? There are endless ways. But I think it sounds like you want to just feed the dump into `psql`. Other options include `pg_restore`, the `COPY` command, or using an ETL tool like Talend Studio, Pentaho Kettle or CloverETL. Anyway, **what's the error message**?

Comment: command:  PGPASSWORD=**** psql -h testredshift.cudmvpnjzyyy.us-west-2.redshift.amazonaws.com -p 5439 -U abcd  -d pagila -f /home/jamy/Desktop/pag_data.sql


ERROR:  LOAD source is not supported. (Hint: only S3 or DynamoDB or EMR based load is allowed) @CraigRinger

Answer (score 3):

Dump your table using a CSV format:

```sql
\copy <your_table_name> TO 'dump_fulename.csv' csv header NULL AS '\N'
```

Upload it to S3, and read it from redshift using:

```sql
COPY schema.table FROM 's3:/...' WITH CREDENTIALS '...' CSV;
```

Source: [Importing Data into Redshift from MySQL and Postgres](https://www.periscope.io/blog/importing-data-into-redshift-from-mysql-and-postgres.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use pg_dump: unload all your data to s3 and use a copy command to load it into Redshift. This is a common mistake.

Comment: Is there any other way?? it looks like little bit complex

Comment: This one is most efficient. You can use postgresql dblink or write your appp.